# shopt -q in terminal no return

Tags: bash, shell

Going through the [Bash reference guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin), trying to understand nullglob and bash in general. But when I try:

```
$shopt -q nullglob
```

I get no return. If nullglob is off, shouldn't I get a 0 return? I don't understand -q option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description of the `-q` option in the Bash

> **Suppresses normal output**; the return status indicates whether the optname is set or unset.

The variable `$?` contains the status of the last command.

```
shopt -q nullglob
echo $?
```

That will print `0` if it's set, `1` if it's not set.

But it's more useful in an `if`:

```
if shopt -q nullglob
then echo nullglob is set
else echo nullglob is not set
fi
```

Comment: Maybe this is a different question, but what constitutes a command that puts something in $? ?

Comment: Every command puts something in `$?`. It always contains the termination status of the last command.

Comment: Any bash tutorial should explain the use of `$?`